# Updating sql-server table from mysql DB

Tags: mysql, sql-server, integration

Integrating 2 systems, we need to insert records from mysql to sql-server:

```
MYSQL                              SQLServer
  Table (Trigger) -----Insert----->  Table
```

How do we do this integration between databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger level integration is not possible, because MySQL does not have the mechanisms to do this work.